# Link in controller to my view with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller and I need to make a link to my view:

```
@projeto.atividades.each do |a|
    @mapa[:tasks] << {
       id:a.id,
       name:<%= link_to a.descricao, edit_atividade_path(atividade) %>
    }
end
```

`a.descricao` = the word that I want to be the link.

`edit_atividade_path(atividade)` = my view.

What is the syntax?

Comment: I don't think you should add links like that in your controller, as Rails use MVC architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
@mapa[:tasks] << {
   id:a.id,
   name: view_context.link_to(a.descricao, edit_atividade_path(atividade))
}
```

Also a point to remember is that in your controller you don't need the `<%` or `%>` scriptlets since its already ruby code.

Comment: /home/elton/devel/sadplan/app/controllers/projetos_controller.rb:27: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}' ... name:view_context.link_to a.descricao, edit_atividade_pa... ... ^ 

Wrong :/

Comment: hmm, @EltonSantos, please try the updated code.  I've added parenthesis around the `link_to` helper.

Comment: undefined local variable or method `atividade' for #<ProjetosController:0xb0ab198>

My view is work very well, but the link dont :l

Comment: @EltonSantos, you probably want `edit_atividate_path(a)` instead of `edit_atividade_path(atividade)`